# Gmail & Python, send different emails with same attachment

Tags: python, gmail, email-attachments, gmail-api

I need to send multiple emails (like 200 customized emails each day), but all have same pdf attachment. Is it possible to upload the attachment only once to save on upload time? 
Even better than that, is it possible to upload the file only once on a google server and each day just reference that file?

Just for reference here is the code (modified a bit from google developer sample code):

```
# main function 
def SendMessageAttachment(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain, attachmentFile):
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    message1 = create_message_with_attachment(sender, to, subject, msgPlain, attachmentFile)
    SendMessageInternal(service, "me", message1)

def SendMessageInternal(service, user_id, message):
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
        print 'Message Id: %s' % message['id']
        return message
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error


def create_message_with_attachment(
    sender, to, subject, message_text, attachmentFile):
    """Create a message for an email.

    Args:
      sender: Email address of the sender.
      to: Email address of the receiver.
      subject: The subject of the email message.
      message_text: The text of the email message.
      file: The path to the file to be attached.

    Returns:
      An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
    """
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject

    msg = MIMEText(message_text)
    message.attach(msg)

    print "create_message_with_attachment: file:", attachmentFile
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(attachmentFile)

    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
    if main_type == 'text':
        fp = open(attachmentFile, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'image':
        fp = open(attachmentFile, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'audio':
        fp = open(attachmentFile, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    else:
        fp = open(attachmentFile, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        fp.close()
    filename = os.path.basename(attachmentFile)
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    message.attach(msg)

    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

Comment: Could you send a single email with all recipients in the `BCC` header?

Comment: @onlynone each email is customized to recipient (such as their names), so not possible to send one email.

Answer (score 0):

the attachment is loaded here:

```
part = MIMEApplication(open("mypdf.pdf","rb").read())
```

but the reference for the header can be anywhere

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename="file.pdf")
msg.attach(part)
```

You could write a function to add this header before sending the mail and iterate over all your recipients.

Comment: Is it uploaded to the server or just loaded to the memory?

Comment: In the memory. it needs to be on the server to `open` it in the first place.

Comment: So this will still upload the attachment for every email to gmail servers, if I understand correctly.

Comment: it will upload the attachment, one time per process call of your script and add this attachment to as many emails you need to send. Imagine large businesses, uploading every file they have to send seperately, that be a bandwith killer.

Comment: Do you mean the attachment is uploaded to the server in this line? part = MIMEApplication(open("mypdf.pdf","rb").read())